# DAX measure with DATEADD function used for collecting data for last month from present month reports not working on year transition period

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

I've got filtering Calendar table for the date I collect reports monthly and I've got Table for calculating staff days on site per visit (DOS). Following code works nicely for all months but December. Please advise changes:

```
    Completed Days on Site DOS = 
CALCULATE(
 SUM(Table[# Actual DOS]),
 DATEADD(Calendar[Deployment Date],1,MONTH), //*Data from the report from one month ahead
 IF(
    MONTH(Table[Data Deployment Date]) = 1,
    YEAR(Table[Visit Date]) = YEAR(Table[Data Deployment Date]) + 1,
    YEAR(Table[Visit Date]) = YEAR(Table[Data Deployment Date])
 ),
 MONTH(Table[Visit Date]) = MONTH(Table[Data Deployment Date]) - 1
)
```

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, instead of this line

```
MONTH(Table[Visit Date]) = MONTH(Table[Data Deployment Date]) - 1
```

should be

```
    MONTH(
     DATE(
        YEAR(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Visit Date]),
        MONTH(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Visit  Date]),
        DAY(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Visit  Date])
     )
    ) = 
    MONTH(
     DATE(
        YEAR(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Data Deployment Date]),
        MONTH(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Data Deployment Date])-1,
        DAY(DOS_History_UpToDeployDate[Data Deployment Date])
     )
    )
```